# Checking if an array contains one integer value

Tags: java, arrays

Don't want to use loops. I tried the below code but it doesn't work for primitive types.

```
if ( Arrays.asList( myMatrix ).contains( -1 ) )
{
    // do something
}
```

What shall be done here?

Comment: You need a loop to do this, and the example you posted demonstrates lazy, inefficient coding

Comment: @ControlAltDel: I agree with that, but in Ezazel's defense, (1) a lot of people advocate using stuff like the Streams API these days , (2) there really should be a `contains` method on `java.util.Arrays`, and (3) that some stuff does not work with `int`, but works with `Integer` is a bit lame.

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid iteration in your code since we need *some* way to test all elements in your array (at least until we will find the one we are looking for). But to make your life easier create some additional utility method like (name could be probably better/more descriptive) `public static boolean contains(int[] array, int element)` which will handle iteration for us. Then simply use it like `if(contains(matrix, -1))`.

---

In Java 8 you could use `IntStream` which handles `int[] myMatrix` array correctly (like `Array.asList` handles `Integer[] myMatrix`).

So as condition you could use something like:

```
IntStream.of(myMatrix).anyMatch(i -> i == -1)
```

Comment: I upvoted, because that is what the question asked for. But I would not do that in this case. Cannot be faster, arguably harder to read.

Comment: @Thilo Agreed. I only posted it as example of how code can look like. But I am surprised that Arrays doesn't have method which handles this task already. EDIT: based on your answer I see we agree on that.

Answer (score 3):

Java should really have a method `contains` on `java.util.Arrays`.

[Commons Lang has it](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#contains%28int[],%20int%29), for example.

So I would either find it in the libraries I already use, or make a static helper method myself (with a simple loop inside).

Answer (score 2):

`"I don't want to use loops"` -- you can't always get what you want, and in fact in this situation, use a loop.

Comment: You could hide that loop behind `contains`, but there is still a loop in there.

Comment: @Thilo: I didn't think that you could try `contains` with an array of primitives. Regardless, I wasn't a big fan of the question and so answered it as a community wiki.

Comment: You cannot directly use `contains` on an array of primitives. You have to jump through some hoops (and potential inefficiencies). But that's more of a failing of Java than the programmer's in my book.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, why are you create `community wiki` for this answer? Just curious.

Comment: @Thilo: thanks. And 1+ to Pshemo's answer, although if I had the energy, I'd look through the source code generated by it.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman: to be honest, I didn't much like the question, **or my answer**.

Comment: @Thilo: and likewise 1+ to your answer. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: I don't like my answer either. Or the other one. Even though all three are correct. Sad situation all around. This kind of stuff makes people roll their eyes at Java.